# GoodData: Deleting and updating metadata objects through API

Tags: api, gooddata

How do you delete / update a metadata object through the API?

For example Scheduled emails: http://docs.gooddata.apiary.io/#reportsanddashboardsbyemail
In the documentation I see how to create a new one or get existing ones. 
How do I delete a Scheduled email?

```
DELETE https://secure.gooddata.com/gdc/md/PROJECT_ID/obj/OBJECT_ID
```

For scheduledMail it works fine, but does it work universally?

How do you update a scheduled email? Does `PUT` work? What request body should I use? Or do I have to delete the old object and create a new one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For each metadata object the DELETE works. For updating the object use the PUT where the body will be response to the same resource from GET request that you can easily edit and send back using PUT to the same resource. So the workflow will be:

1. `GET` metadata object
2. Update the object body (JSON)
3. `PUT` it back on the same resource from which you got it

This works for all metadata objects. You can easily recognised those objects by

`/obj/OBJECT-ID`

Thanks for the question!